# GIT project divided in two branches

Tags: git, branch

lets suppose I have project that is divided into two disjunctive sets. Both sets contain some directories and files, here is simple example:

Repository:

- DIR1 - Branch1
- DIR2 - Branch2

The thing is, I need to have both branches/dirs visible in folder (repository) for correct working when developing it (its web-based / php, js ).

How can I achieve this? When I switch some branch to edit it, it shows me only files from selected branch.

I tried to switch to Branch1, then copy content from DIR2 (to get the project working) and add copied files from DIR2 to .gitignore in Branch1, but when i switch to Branch2 and then to Branch1 all files from Branch2 are deleted..

Comment: Well that's how branches are supposed to work..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your asking is completely possible, I found the Git Hub Documentation on merging branches helpful though https://help.github.com/articles/merging-branches/

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi gwar9,

there is possibility to create new branch, lets call it "complete" and merge both branches - "Branch1" and "Branch2" into it. But this approach is quiet uncomfortable, because I need to often check if its project working when i am working on (current active branch is) Branch1 (or Branch2)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you are trying to achieve? this behviour is exactly what branches are for. there is a solution to your problem and it's called submodules.

You can split the repository into:
repository A which contains branch DIR1
repository B which contains branch DIR2

then you can add a submodule to repository A which points to repository B.
in this way you can achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi DanM, 

submodules resolves "simplified" example i've described in my question, thanks for thatm but unfortunately submodule does not resolve my specific needs. 

I have webbased project with directory-structure below and I need to divide dirs/files into 2 or more branches. One file can be only in one particular branch. Something like this

- dir1         (branchA)    
- dir2   
--subdir1  (branchA)
-- subdir2 (branchB)

git submodule is only able to create "directory" which contains repo and it does not fullfill my needs.